# Teradata: Identify all rows with a value in column A where atleast one one in column B equals a certain value

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata V15. I want to identify all rows of column A where atleast one rows of column B is equal to a certain value. A mockup dataset is below with Experiment #s and the result of the trial (P-Pass, F-Fail). The actual data contain several million Experiments, with many trials for each. I want to tag all rows of an experiment as F (failed) if atleast one trial has Failed.

I've tried a brute for of just using `UPDATE on Experiment_Result with F for all rows of Experiment_NUM in (SELECT (distinct Experiment_NUM) where Trial_Result = F)`.

I want to see if there is a better way using QUALIFY, RANK or any similar functions.

```
Experiment_NUM  Trial_Result    Experiment_Result
1               P   
1               P   
1               P   
2               F   
2               F   
2               P   
2               P   
2               P   
3               F   
3               P   
4               P   
4               P   
4               P   
4               P   
4               P   
4               P   
4               P
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've tried so far?  Looks like a pretty reasonable approach to me.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The approach worked but some colleagues of mine felt this was a brute force method and there may be a more robust solution with qualify or rank. I've looked at these functions but couldn't find a way to make it work hence my inquiry.